# Как узнать, в какой строчке JS устанавливается высота элемента (style="height:600px;")?

Tags: javascript, css

При просмотре DOM в браузере в режиме разработчика можно увидеть, в какой строке какого CSS файла задаются стили для данного элемента. А можно ли как-нибудь узнать не CSS, а JS  (style="height:600px;", например) ?

Comment: задаваться может десятком разных способов: прямым заданием .height(600), var height = 600; .height(height), var height = набор действий которые это число высчитывают, ... проще всего наверное попытаться представить по какому селектору задается и искать где у этого селектора задается скажем .height(), или .attr('style', 'height:' + height + 'px') и так далее ....

Comment: @MedvedevDev а еще значение может просто вычисляться и напрямую числа просто нет

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, "var height = набор действий которые это число высчитывают"

Comment: @MedvedevDev вообще не факт. во-первых может быть let. во-вторых имя может быть в какой-нибудь либе и просто быть h (а после минификации и z), в-третьих оно может быть вообще вот так: `.css('height', calcSize())`, где в `calcSize` может быть какая-то формула, в-четвертых и далее можно придумывать бесконечно

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, блин, ну это как пример же .... ну чего ты придираешься ... я же написал в самом начале, что вариаций на тему может быть много.

Answer (score 1):

Например можно в chrome поставить точку останова на изменение атрибута элемента (в данном случае style).

Для этого нужно:

1. Открыть консоль разработчика
2. Найти момент, когда элемент уже создан но
   пуст/или не имеет этого атрибута и остановить там выполнение страницы (например в сам тег, добавить debugger;
3. Выделить DOM элемент > **Break on** > **attribute modifications**
4. Продолжить выполнение скрипта
5. Скрипт остановится, когда у тега поменяются атрибуты
6. Во вкладки **Sources** > Call Stack можно увидеть откуда был вызван скрипт

**Удачного коддинга!**

PS. Также можно попробовать найти по каким-то условным уникальным именам (типа идентификатор, или вдруг класс элемента). Для этого можно кликнуть **CTRL+SHIFT+F** и ввести то, что хотите найти. Он будет искать всюду, что было загружено на странице